# Maven: Use different global profiles for different modules in one build

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a multi-module POM project.

In my settings.xml I keep a number of profiles containing details for connecting to various servers. This are used by the persistence units of the modules.

What I need is to use two different profiles (one for one module and an other one for the rest of them) in the same build. Not build all profiles in once, as some other questions here on SO ask for.

My best case scenario would be to be able to set one profile as default, what I have now, and just assign the other profile to the one module that needs it, without having to define the profile again anywhere else.

Important, I have managed to get the functionality I need by using mvn with different profiles on the terminal but I want to be able to do this through the pom so that I can build the whole thing in Netbeans and Jenkins.

Is that even possible?

Comment: What you can do on command line you can usually do in Jenkins, just give the proper commands in your build config.

Comment: +1 for keeping the command-line arguments, but alternatively you could specify a list of `activeProfile` in the `settings.xml` used for the build

Comment: Still there is Netbeans, or any other IDE, I would like my project to be as portable as possible. Soon I will have to share it with other people and I would like them to be able to just build it in their IDE without any extra configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure but using activation by properties you might be able to activate a profile when a property is in a pom of a module. See http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation

Comment: @Aaron I have seen this tag but haven't been able to use it for my case. How can I specify which profile to use where?

Comment: @Arch use different `settings.xml` for the different builds? Use activation as suggested by Redlab? Honestly specifying the list of profiles with `-P` for each build seems the best option.

Comment: Also most IDE allow you to select the active profiles. Netbeans : http://wiki.netbeans.org/File:Configurations_MavenBestPractices.png

Comment: @Redlab I have tried that but in that way I need to define the profile in the individual pom right?

Comment: I don't know, I have never had the need to have different profiles activated for different modules of one build. But the profile in your settings.xml should also be activated if the property in a pom has the required value.

Comment: @Redlab Also the problem with Netbeans is that by building the parent pom using one profile, the profile is applied to all of the modules even if I have specified a different one for each module

Comment: What exactly do you mean with different profiles for different builds @Aaron?

Comment: regarding your answer to Redlab, profiles are inherited by the pom's children, so you should avoid using profiles to avoid that. I didn't mean much about different profiles for different build, I thought that was what you wanted ; isn't it?

Comment: @Aaron yes, but I would like all the profiles to be declared in the global settings.xml file, just as they are right now. Otherwise I would have to declare the same profile multiple times and in the event of a change in a value I would need to update it for every module independently.

Comment: @Arch I don't see the problem, you can reference with `mvn goal -P profile1,profile2` profiles from a global `settings.xml` file

Comment: @Aaron as I have said I have been able to do this, what I want to achieve is embed this functionality in the pom files.

Answer (score 0):

Initially i thought maybe some thing like this.

in settings.xml profile

```
    <activation>
    <property>
      <name>activator.one</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    </activation>
```

in pom.xml of a module

```
    <properties>
       <activator.one>true</activator.one>
    </properties>
```

maybe this will activate the profile with the activator only when the property is set to true. Which is then only in the pom of a certain module.

**BUT** http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Activating-a-profile-in-settings-xml-based-on-a-property-set-in-pom-xml-td512562.html

Profiles can not be activated during build!

**Thus**

Is it not better to name the profiles different in your modules so that the names are totally different. And activate them all. 
Like connections_mysqldb_module_a, connections_hsqldb_module_b 
You'll have bunch of profiles but if you make sure the names do not overlap between modules you can always choose on a per module basis and still build everything at once.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but it didn't work. I even disabled the <activeByDefault> for the default profile and nothing changed.